# Question about the validity of plane separation proof in Hartshorne

Tags: geometry

In Hartshorne's *Euclid and Beyond* there is a proof of what is referred to as the Plane Separation theorem:

> Let $l$ be any line then the set of points not lying on $l$ can be divided into two non-empty subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. Two points $A, B$ not on $l$ belong to the same set ($S_1$ or $S_2$) if and only if the segment $\overline{AB}$ does not intersect $l$.
> 2. Two points $A, C$ not on $l$ belong to the opposite sets (one in $S_1$ and the other in $S_2$) if and only if the segment $\overline{AC}$ intersects $l$ in a point.

The proof on page 75, begins by establishing that the relation $\sim$, defined to be either $A = B$ or $\overline{AB}$ does not intersect $l$, is an equivalence relation. In order to show transitivity there are two cases, the first one (that I have issue with) is when $A \sim B$, $B \sim C$ and $A, B, C$ are non-colinear. He states:

> Case 1: Supppose $A, B, C$ are not colinear. Then we have a triangle $ABC$. Since, $A \sim B$, $l$ does not meet $\overline{AB}$. Since $B \sim C$, $l$ does not meet $\overline{BC}$. Now by Pasch's axiom (B4), it follows that $l$ does not meet $\overline{AC}$. Hence, $A \sim C$.

What I have issue is that I don't believe Pasch's Axiom is used correctly. Pasch's Axiom, according to Hartshorne is:

> (Pasch) Let $A, B, C$ be three non-colinear points, and $l$ be a line not containing any of $A,B, C$. If **$l$ contains a point $D$ lying between $A$ and $B$**, then it must also contain either a point lying between $A$ and $C$ or a point lying between $B$ and $C$, but not both. [Emphasis mine]

This axiom doesn't appear to say anything about the case when $l$ fails to contain such a point $D$ (As is the case with Hartshorne's Case 1). Why is Hartshorne allowed to make the conclusion he did? Is there a way to reconcile this, or am I thinking about it incorrectly?

Comment: Contrapositive, look it up.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Ah ok. I wish he had mentioned that it came from the contrapositive. Makes more sense now. Thanks.